# Protractor: How to assign a element to a variable dynamically on run time

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have table. I have to click on "edit" button of td that matches with a specific text.

What I am doing is I am getting all tds and iterating each of them to match the text. Once the text is found I will find it tr and then click its edit button.

```
   var tdModule = element.all(by.cssContainingText('td', strnewUserName));

   var elem;
    tdModule.each((value) => {

          value.getText().then((text) => { 
            console.log(text);                     
             if (text == strnewUserName) {

                var tr = value.element(by.xpath('ancestor::tr'));
                elem= tr.element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.edit(row)"]'));
               }


         });
     });

     elem.click();
```

Now the problem here is that the code throws error : "cannot read property 'click' of undefined". I think its because the variable elem is not assigned. I am beginner in JS.

I also have an another option and that is to break the loop. But .each loop cannot be broken. I also tried 'for' loop. but it also gave error.

Here is the code with for loop.

```
tdModule.count().then((count)=>{
  console.log("c = "+ count)

   for(let i = 0 ; i< count ; i++)
    {

        tdModule.get(i).getText().then((text)=>{

            if(text == strnewUserName){
               var tr = value.element(by.xpath('ancestor::tr'));
                 tr.element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.edit(row)"]')).click();


            break;
            }

         })
     }

   });
```